What is the connection between the Schwarz Lemma and contraction mappings?

What is the connection between the Schwarz Lemma and contraction mappings? How does the behavior of holomorphic functions in the unit disk, as described by the Schwarz Lemma, relate to the concept of contraction mappings in analysis?"

"I’ve been studying both the Schwarz Lemma and the concept of contraction mappings in different contexts, and I noticed some similarities. The Schwarz Lemma deals with holomorphic functions in the unit disk, stating that if a function $( f )$ fixes the origin and maps the unit disk into itself, then the magnitude of $( f(z) )$ is less than or equal to $( |z| )$, and $( |f'(0)| \leq 1 )$. This makes me think of contraction mappings, where a function brings points closer together. The Schwarz Lemma seems to impose a kind of 'contractive behavior' on holomorphic functions, especially since the derivative at the origin is bounded."
"In contraction mapping theory, a function $( f )$ on a metric space is a contraction if there exists a constant $( c < 1 )$ such that for any two points $( x )$ and $( y )$, the distance between $( f(x) )$ and $( f(y) )$ is less than $( c )$ times the distance between ( x ) and ( y ). This contraction property ensures that the function pulls points closer together.
When I look at the Schwarz Lemma, particularly the inequality $( |f(z)| \leq |z| )$, it seems as though the holomorphic function ( f ) behaves similarly, since it doesn't increase distances from the origin in the unit disk. It feels analogous to the contractive behavior, except instead of a general metric space, this happens within the complex unit disk.
"Is this connection between the Schwarz Lemma and contraction mappings just an analogy, or is there a deeper relationship between the two concepts? Can the Schwarz Lemma be seen as a special case of a contraction mapping in a certain metric space? If so, how do we formally establish this connection?"
Thanking you

If you consider the so-called pseudo-hyperbolic metric $d(z,w) = |\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{w}z}|$ then, according to the Schwarz-Pick lemma any holomorphic self mapping of the unit disk $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is a contraction in this metric: $d(f(w), f(z)) \le d(w, z)$. The same is true for the hyperbolic metric $\rho(z,w) = \tanh^{-1}d(z,w)$.
